# Is it acceptable to promote a Area51 Proposal on this Meta?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it would be okay to promote an Area51 proposal on the meta here.

I think it is related to the History SE as it is an SE for Anthropology and Sociology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "promote", but I suspect a lot of our users will be enthusiastic to see that succeed, as it would be great migration target for a lot of the off-topic questions we get here that we are currently forced to just close.

Comment: Tempted to insist you promote [my sister's book](https://www.amazon.com/Colonial-Entanglement-Constituting-Twenty-First-Century-Directions/dp/0807872903) in exchange. :-)

Comment: So, is this generalisable? Every Area51 promo OK, just related ones?

Comment: In my case, I'd just prefer to see related ones. I've also been less-than-supportive in the past for proposals that are proper subsets of history (eg: HSM) as a subset of a site getting less than 10 questions a day itself seems like a really Bad Idea(tm).